# How set ad-hoc mode on nexus 4 with cynogenmod

Tags: android

I'm tryng to set ad-hoc mode on my galaxy nexus 4 with rom cyanogenmod but i've some problems.
I have a executable file for load kernel modules called "wifiloader" for activate ad-hoc mode, i made this reading this code:   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware_legacy/+/745e7fd4e09db2b47371338ee54c54255e286473/wifi/wifi.c

Besides i also found (searching on internet) a executable of iwconfig for android(with a Samsung S2 with gingerbread works) but with nexus 4 i have this error:

```
./wifiloader start
Starting wifi... OK.
./iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid my_network channel 9
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Any suggestion? Where i can find a executable of iwconfig for this version of android? Is there another way to activate ad-hoc mode?
I'm getting crazy :(